# Aligning text from edge to edge in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, margin

So I'm doing my first web site ever, and I don't know what to do with my text.
It is just standing like that, I searched everywhere but I don't know why nothing is working. I want it to be more wide, it has large edges and i want to change that. I just started learning the HTML language.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Open your webpage in Chrome, hit F12 and analyze the wonders of css :) beside that: Not enough information, screenshots are evil and you should read up on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - providing the SO Community with enough information to help you will benefit any questions you phrase

Comment: atleast show your code

Comment: done, there was some max-width from something and i chenaged it.
and thank you patrick for your help, the next questions that I will make will be better, this was my first one.